# How to parse an encoded url that is a query parameter in route Angular 1?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

In my routes, I have this. However, I can't find a way to properly decode the url. The page just redirects to the base url (not the redirect url). The url is encoded so `/` are `%2F` and what not but I don't know how to make it so I can accept it as a query parameter.

```js
.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
   $stateProvider
   .state('example', {
     url: '/{test}/{queryParameterUrl}',
     controller: 'exampleCtrl as example',
     template: require('./partials/test.html')
   });
```

Comment: Do you have control over the code triggering the redirect?

Comment: I think curly brackets are for regular expressions. You might need `url: '/:test/:urlredirect'`. Also add `controllerAs: 'example'`

Comment: @Protozoid I have this angular app within a laravel app. So currently the url structure for this page would be /exampleroute/fun/{test}/{urlredirect} but since it's not liking urlredirect it just goes to /exampleroute/fun

Comment: @AlekseySolovey No luck same issue.

Comment: Are you redirecting via the state reference? e.g. `$state.go('example', {test: 'value', urlredirect: 'othervalue'})`

Comment: @Protozoid I am using $stateProvider (added above)

Comment: @savvvycode1 I'm not asking about the definition of the state, I'm asking about the code triggering the redirect e.g. a click on an `<a>` tag

Comment: @Protozoid once I try and go to the url as defined in my state, it automatically redirects me to the base url.

Comment: Can you provide the code were the redirect happens?

Comment: I'm not sure if the confusion is because one of the parameters name is urlredirect. Let me just change it to queryParameterUrl

Comment: The issue is the queryParameterUrl is not being properly recognized.

Comment: Do you want to use the value of `queryParameterUrl` to redirect to that URL at some point?

Comment: @Protozoid yes but I want to store it first then on button click I was going to redirect. But that I know, it's just I've never ran into trying to accept an encoded url as a query string parameter.

Answer (score 0):

In your `exampleController` you can access the state parameter, parse it and use it to redirect later on, as such:

```
app.controller('exampleCtrl', ['$state', function ($state) {
    var exampleCtrl = this;

    exampleCtrl.parsedRedirectUrl = $state.params.urlredirect.replace(/%2F/g, '/')
}]);
```

And in HTML, for example, redirect using a link

```
<a href="{{example.parsedRedirectUrl}}">Redirect</a>
```

P.S. In your state definition, use `controllerAs`

```
.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('example', {
         url: '/{test}/{urlredirect}',
         controller: 'exampleCtrl',
         controllerAs: 'example',
         template: require('./partials/test.html')
    });
```

Comment: Hey Protozoid, thanks for the feedback. I actually was able to solve the issue with https://www.coditty.com/code/angular-ui-router-replacing-slash-with-2f-quick-fix . For some reason angular ui router was not liking the encoded /